# How to use Google's Text-to-Speech API in Python

Tags: python, api, text-to-speech

My key is ready to go to make requests and get speech from text from Google.
I tried these commands and many more.
The docs offer no straight forward solutions to getting started with Python that I've found. I don't know where my API key goes along with the JSON and URL

[One solution in their docs here is for CURL.](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol). But involves downloading a txt after the request that has to be sent back to them in order to get the file. Is there a way to do this in Python that doesn't involve the txt I have to return them?
I just want my list of strings returned as audio files.

[image: My Code]

(I put my actual key in the block above. I'm just not going to share it here.)

Comment: [_docs offer no solutions for Python_](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-python)?

Comment: I saw this. I meant in the OP, there is no Python equivalent in the link I posted. I don't understand what this link is, (the code). I don't understand where my API key goes. Maybe that's all I need. Where does this code see the API? I haven't been able to find a way into using this stuff anywhere after looking all day.

Comment: When you say API Key I assume you mean the API key you set up when setting up Google Cloud correct? It might be worth reading the [full set up from the beginning](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries). The API key you downloaded in JSON format is something you set in your environment as `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` (see step 2). They then have further instructions in how you get your [Python environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup) set up correctly.

Comment: As aug pointed out, there is a Python quickstart at the link that they provided. The Python quickstart provides equivalent functionality to the CURL sample that you linked to.
Also as aug mentions, you need to use a service account, not an API key.

Comment: Eric, you write these docs? Respectfully, They are very opaque and confusing. Hard to find. It's like there are 3 decoy versions of everything. Not linked to where I signed up. Yesterday was 10 hours trying to get Python to do what that CURL command did. Today, about 8 hours spent trying to figure out where to enter the voice name and that it was dif than language_code. You downvoted my question?

Comment: and I entered my API key in my shell. It works now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Configure Python App for JSON file and Install Client Library

1. Create a Service Account
2. Create a Service Account Key using the Service Account [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey?project=YOURPROJECT)
3. The JSON file downloads and save it securely
4. Include the Google Application Credentials in your Python App
5. Install the library: `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-texttospeech`

Using Google's Python examples found:
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries
Note: In Google's example it is not including the name parameter correctly.
and
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/texttospeech/cloud-client/quickstart.py

### Below is the modified from the example using google app credentials and wavenet voice of a female.

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/home/yourproject-12345.json"

from google.cloud import texttospeech

# Instantiates a client
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

# Set the text input to be synthesized
synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text="Do no evil!")

# Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") 
# ****** the NAME
# and the ssml voice gender ("neutral")
voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code='en-US',
    name='en-US-Wavenet-C',
    ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)

# Select the type of audio file you want returned
audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

# Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
# voice parameters and audio file type
response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)

# The response's audio_content is binary.
with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
    # Write the response to the output file.
    out.write(response.audio_content)
    print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

---

### Voices,Name, Language Code, SSML Gender, Etc

List of Voices: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices

In the above code example I changed the voice from Google's example code to include the name parameter and to use the Wavenet voice (much improved but more expensive $16/million chars) and the SSML Gender to FEMALE.

```
voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code='en-US',
        name='en-US-Wavenet-C',
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)
```

Comment: In the voice selection part here is "language_code='en-US',
    ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)", do you know how I can get the 'en-US-Wavenet-F' voice on the Google TTS sample page?

Comment: Found their list. Weird cause no matter the name of the voice, all voices of the same language code sound the same https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices. In other words, 'en-US' always returns the exact same voice. No change if I change it to 'en-US-Wavenet-F' or anything else.

Comment: Got it. For anyone's possible future reference, after language_code you add     name='en-US-Wavenet-F', below that line to get what I've been trying to get.

Comment: How to use this example to call an external JSON representation including both ssml and voice selection parameters like this https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml#tips_for_using_ssml ?

Comment: How come doing **speech_client.list_voices()** does not list the voices with Wavenet ?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer and lost the link among 150 Google documentation pages I had open.

```
#(Since I'm using a Jupyter Notebook)
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/Path/to/JSON/file/jsonfile.json"
from google.cloud import texttospeech

# Instantiates a client
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

# Set the text input to be synthesized
synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text="Hello, World!")

# Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
# voice gender ("neutral")
voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code='en-US',
    ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)

# Select the type of audio file you want returned
audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

# Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
# voice parameters and audio file type
response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)

# The response's audio_content is binary.
with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
    # Write the response to the output file.
    out.write(response.audio_content)
    print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

My time consuming pursuit was to try to send the request through a JSON with Python, but this appears to be through there own modules, which works fine. 
Notice the default voice gender is 'neutral'.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to avoid using the google Python API, you can simply do this:

```
import requests 
import json

url = "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize"

text = "This is a text"

data = {
        "input": {"text": text},
        "voice": {"name":  "fr-FR-Wavenet-A", "languageCode": "fr-FR"},
        "audioConfig": {"audioEncoding": "MP3"}
      };

headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "X-Goog-Api-Key": "YOUR_API_KEY" }

r = requests.post(url=url, json=data, headers=headers)
content = json.loads(r.content)
```

It is similar to what you did but you need to include your API key.